# Analyze doPostBack

Tags: asp.net, firebug, fiddler

For example let's use https://www.technicalcommunity.com/Pages/groups.aspx
When you click on User Group header link, it run's doPostBack, i want to analyze this postback. I tried to use Firebug (ffb4) but saw nothing + it brokes action and form with details never shows. I tried to use Fiddler, but postback never appear in request list.
How can i see postback details?

Comment: He's complaining that you don't often "Accept" answers to your questions. Some folks are less likely to bother answering questions because they want to get more credit for their work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see a request in Fiddler, that means that no request was sent. That suggests, in turn, that you have broken JavaScript code in your page which is preventing the PostBack request from being sent to the server.